# Pattern matching grant statement in java using Pattern & Matcher class

Tags: java, pattern-matching, sql-grant

For a DB2 example grant would look like below.

```
grant insert,update,delete on ABC.TABLE_NAME to group DACT_RW, group DACT_RW_BATCH1
```

I am trying to build a regex pattern using something like:

```
Pattern.compile("[g|G][r|R][a|A][n|N][t|T][ \\t\\n\\x0B\\f\\r]+[i|I][n|N][s|S][e|E][r|R][t|T][ \\t\\n\\x0B\\f\\r]*[,][ \\t\\n\\x0B\\f\\r]*[u|U][p|P][d|D][a|A][t|T][e|E][ \\t\\n\\x0B\\f\\r]*[,][ \\t\\n\\x0B\\f\\r]*[d|D][e|E][l|L][e|E][t|T][e|E][ \\t\\n\\x0B\\f\\r]+[o|O][n|N][ \\t\\n\\x0B\\f\\r]+" + eodAppendedDbObjectName + "[ \\t\\n\\x0B\\f\\r]+[t|T][o|O][ \\t\\n\\x0B\\f\\r]+[g|G][r|R][o|O][u|U][p|P][ \\t\\n\\x0B\\f\\r]+DACT_RW[ \\t\\n\\x0B\\f\\r]*[,][g|G][r|R][o|O][u|U][p|P][ \\t\\n\\x0B\\f\\r]+DACT_RW_BATCH1$");
```

But somehow, even if I specify correct grants, it is not getting matched.

Could you suggest what's wrong in above pattern compilation?. OR suggest better way to match the pattern in java.

Comment: If you use Pattern.compile(patternStr, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE) you don't need to check on all upper/lower-case combinations and your pattern gets less complicated

Comment: `[g|G]` matches one of `'g'`, `'|'`, `'G'` (yes, also the `'|'` char!). Inside a character class, the "normal" meta character have no "special powers".

Comment: @  Stefan Neubert :
I am aware of Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE option. But I cannot use it to match my pattern as few words in the statement is case-sensitive.

Comment: @Bart Kiers:
Its really a useful comment, as with [g|G] it matches char | as well. But it is of less importance to me. I would like to allow G or g as part of 'grant' word here. Any alternate way is there to match pattern in Java?

Comment: This is your regex without the stuff you don't need: `grant insert\s*,\s*update\s*,\s*delete\s+on\s+ABC.TABLE_NAME\s+to\s+group\s+DACT_RW\s*,\s*group\s+DACT_RW_BATCH1`. Use it with `Pattern.compile("regex", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher("your string").matches();`

Comment: I agree with @Alex (+1). It is cleaner with CASE_INSENSITIVE. I know the object names are case sensitive but you probably shouldn't have another object with the same name just different case. We have ran into this problem with tables in uppercase and a view by the same name in lower case was very confusing for users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simplified the statement by replacing `[ \\t\\n\\x0B\\f\\r]` with `\\s` and this works.

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    String[] vals = {"grant     insert,update,delete on ABC.TABLE_NAME to group DACT_RW, group DACT_RW_BATCH1"};
    String eodAppendedDbObjectName = "ABC.TABLE_NAME";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[gG][rR][aA][nN][tT]\\s+[iI][nN][sS][eE][rR][tT]\\s*,\\s*[uU][pP][dD][aA][tT][eE]\\s*,\\s*[dD][eE][lL][eE][tT][eE]\\s+[oO][nN]\\s+" + eodAppendedDbObjectName + "\\s+[tT][oO]\\s+[gG][rR][oO][uU][pP]\\s+DACT_RW\\s*,\\s*[gG][rR][oO][uU][pP]\\s+DACT_RW_BATCH1$");        
    for (String s : vals) {
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
        if (m.matches()) {
            System.out.println(s + " matches.");
        } else {
            System.out.println(s + " does not match.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Complete/Update with CASE_INSENSITIVE